# Theming a rails app via plugin or engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What's the best way to go about this?  I've tried a bunch of different things but can't quite get the hooks in right.  Tons of googling and I can't get it.

I can get everything working right but I cannot seem to override the child apps views/layouts/application.html.erb ... I need to copy over all assets with the gem and have the plugin/engine/gem/whatever's application.html.erb pull from those assets.  Help please?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery-UI has a whole spiel on theming, which also allows it to be dynamic across several different themes. Check out http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Comment: Thanks for this one, i was looking for something very similar.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget about [Bootstrap from Twitter](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). You can just install these and mention the file_name in your layouts and you are good to go.

In fact, in most cases, you can also just copy them in your assets folders and you are ready to go.